# Delete and Add object at same index in Nested Object

Tags: javascript

Object :

```
var userData = {
  "a1":{"a":"1"},
  "b2":{"b":"2"},
  "c3":{"c":"3"},
  "d4":{"d":"4"},
  "e5":{"e":"5"},
};
```

I need to delete Object with key "a1" and place a new object i.e. "f6" at same place.
i.e.

```
userData["f6"] = userData["a1"];
userData["f6"].new = "true"; 
delete userData["a1"];
```

Output:

```
userData = {
  "b2":{"b":"2"},
  "c3":{"c":"3"},
  "d4":{"d":"4"},
  "e5":{"e":"5"},  
  "f6":{"a":"1", new:true},
};
```

Expected O/p:

```
var userData = {
  "f6":{"a":"1", new:true},
  "b2":{"b":"2"},
  "c3":{"c":"3"},
  "d4":{"d":"4"},
  "e5":{"e":"5"},
};
```

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Objects do not have a specific order, so you would need to use an array to keep same position

Comment: What you have is a **JavaScript object** and has nothing to do with JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript, objects have no specific order for their properties. When you see them as a JSON, the properties are shown in the same order they where declared or added. To mantain a specific order, you may do changes in your object and implement an `Array`.